# How to find address of css and js files?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure this is a really simple question, but I'm a noob and can't figure it out. I'm trying to mess around with the `Twitter-Bootstrap` starter template to help myself learn `HTML`, `CSS`, and `JS`. I copied and pasted the source code into TextWrangler and opened the `html` file in Firefox. No bootstrap functionality.

I'm almost certain it's because lines like `<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">` need to be altered to reflect the css/js files' addresses on my own computer. If that's the problem, how do I do this?

Here is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
      <p>Use this document as a way to quick start any new project.<br> All you get is this message and a barebones HTML document.</p>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in your assumption that it's because of the `<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">` line.

This line is a reference to the css file. What you will need to do is save the bootstrap files to your computer in folder somewhere.

To do this, download bootstrap from http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/ and copy the css, img and js folders into your folder.

Now in your file in TextWrangler change the href attribute to "css/bootstrap.css" it will look like this `<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`.

Now save your file as index.html in the same directory as the other folders you copied in.

You will want to do the same for all other references like this one for instance `<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">`.

You will also see at the bottom there are references to some JavaScript files. Change those too.

Good luck!

Comment: It works now! Thanks a lot! It's so frustrating when you know the answer to your problem is simple but you still can't figure it out.